# Jenkins job to spin up AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, groovy, continuous-integration

I want to be able to run a Jenkins job that spins up a Windows AWS EC2 instance for me.

How do I go about this? Should I use the AWS EC2 plugin for Jenkins or create my own script to do it?

Comment: Is the job simply to provision the instance or will you be using Jenkins to act upon that instance after creation? Also are any of your other builds going to be doing EC2 things?

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli Thanks for the reply. The job will be simply to provision the instance. Spin it up so I can connect to it and go from there. None of my other builds will be doing EC2 things. I assume I need to have AWS CLI installed on the Jenkins server for going the script route, correct?